# kotlin httpservletrequest object to string

Tags: http, servlets, kotlin

When converting http servlet request object to string, I am always getting a "" string. This is my code.

```
private fun getBody(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
    var inputAsString = ""
    try {
        var inputStream: InputStream  = request.inputStream
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputAsString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
        }
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        throw ex
    }
    return inputAsString
}
```

Comment: I am using application/json as content-type

Answer (score 1):

1) Your code might look better if you rewrite it like this:

```
private fun getBody(request: HttpServletRequest): String = request
    .inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
```

2) Your problem is not in this code, because it works!